# Adding a breakpoint to breakpoint navigator for a Core Data error

Tags: ios, core-data, breakpoints

I'm trying to track down a bug in an app which logs an error in the simulator, but doesn't crash in the simulator or on my testing device. I think I've got a handle on what to do once I can figure out where the problematic code is located, but I'm having a heck of a time figuring out what call is generating it.

```
CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class "OneOfMyManagedObjects"
```

I'd like to add a breakpoint that stops execution on that error. How would I set the breakpoint navigator to stop execution when that error is logged in the console?

**What I've Tried:**

So far, I threw some log statements in `AppDelegate.swift` and the initial `ViewController` to "see what's going on". Additionally, I've thrown in some manual breakpoints in hopes of tracking down the issue that's generating the console error, but it's taking forever and a day to step through everything. Given the issue lives somewhere between AppDelegate and `viewDidLoad` of the initial `ViewController`, I'm baffled why it's taking me so long to spot the problem.

I've added an exception breakpoint for all exceptions in the breakpoint navigator, but this error doesn't appear to be enough to stop execution. I do think it's enough to cause a problem for a minority of users, which is why I'm trying to clean it up.

Comment: did u add exception breakpoint in xcode ?

Comment: Yes.I added one for all exceptions in the breakpoint navigator.

Comment: how u r checking for the error ?

Comment: I nearly 100% certain it lives in AppDelegate.swift. I threw some log statements in to see what's "going on" and I tried to set some breakpoints at places that made sense and stepped through. I'm pretty sure I'm taking longer than I should to figure out where the issue lives. I'm trying to figure out how to set an automated breakpoint and backtrace to see where it's coming from.

Comment: This is possibly due to a var definition along the lines: `var myObject = OneOfMyManagedObjects()`.  Search your code for something like that.

Comment: @pbasdf Thank you. That was it! I'm using a `tabBarController`. The initial tab is 0 and the object generating the error is displayed on only tab 3. The only time the object in question is called on tab 0 is a local reference inside a save method that's called by the user. Could the `tabBarController` be causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special thanks to **pbasdf** for pointing me in the right direction.

My app uses a TabBarController with 4 tabs. The initial tab is tab 0, so I was looking for a problem between AppDelegate.swift and `InitialVC`'s `viewDidLoad`. In reality, my problem lived on `Tab3ViewController` where `OneOfMyManagedObjects` are displayed.

I had a global variable set on `Tab3ViewController` that looked like this:

```
// this was the problem
var oneOfMyManagedObjectsToEdit = OneOfMyManagedObjects()

// I changed it to this and the error went away
var oneOfMyManagedObjectsToEdit: OneOfMyManagedObjects?
```

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction towards resolution of this problem.